# Аккордион не работает как на примере

Tags: bootstrap, php

[Пример аккордиона](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) работает так, если нажать на одну и потом нажать на другую, то первый закроется. А у меня первый остается открытым. Вроде все делаю как в примере.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TEST</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <?php 
                for($i=1; $i < 5; $i++){
                    echo accordion('accordion2', 'Bla_'.$i.'<span class="label label-success pull-right">Зеленый</span>', 'Hello world <button>BTN</button>'); 
                }   
            ?>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".collapse").collapse();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    function accordion($main_id, $head, $body){ 
        static $num = 0;
        $num++;
        return  
        '<div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                 <a class="accordion-toggle" 
                 data-toggle="collapse" 
                 data-parent="#'.$main_id.'" 
                 href="#collapse'.$num.'">' . $head . '</a>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse'.$num.'" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    '.$body.'
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Уфф, что-то я с этим маркдаун не лажу
http://pastebin.com/cjXSEGMT

Comment: Хм, в реальном сайте все работает как надо. Только надо было убрать "in". Возможно потому что надо было в еще один DIV вложить